# React-Native Android issue upgrade from 0.18.0 to 0.19.0

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Recently i upgraded existing Android application from 0.18.0 to 0.19.0 and try to run but its giving error like

> ReferenceError: can't find variable _fbBatchedBridge (line 1 in the
>   generated bundle)" and if reload  it again error change to "Unable to
>   download JS bundle

.

used following changes.

1 change the react-native version in package.json from 0.18.0 to 0.19.0.

2 change react-native version app/build.gradle dependencies.

3 sudo npm install.

4 react-native start.

5 react-native run-android.

also try adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 and dev setting option for IP adress and remove old bablerc

```
"scripts": {
    "clean:babelrc": "find ./node_modules -name react-packager -prune -o -name '.babelrc' -print | xargs rm -f",
    "postinstall": "npm run clean:babelrc"
  }
```

but still its giving same error.

could any one help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. In the developer menu (open it by shaking your device) you need to go in **Dev Settings** then **Debug server host & port for device**. There you need to enter your local ip address followed by the port (for example 192.168.1.10:8081). 
You can find your local IP address by running `ifconfig` in a terminal (you can find it under en0 I think).
Your device and computer must also be on the same wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

RN updates also comes with Native OS templates updates, try running `react-native upgrade` to update your iOS/Android files.